# Prove that a sequence is bounded if and only if it is bounded above and bounded below.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that a sequence is bounded if and only if it is bounded above and bounded below.

- I think I need to show that there is a sequence ${a_n}$ that is in between a k that is less than or equal to all the terms of the sequence and a k that is greater than or equal to all the terms of the sequence such that $k ≤ {a_n} ≤ K$, I just do not know if this right direction to go or how to fill in the missing steps in order to make my proof make sense. Would I need to set up two limits of $a_n$? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am confused by your query.  I think the place to start is to find the **exact** definitions of bounded above, bounded below, and bounded, presumably **straight out of a textbook**.  If, after you have done that, you still need help, please edit your query to include the three definitions that you have found.  Alternatively, if you solve the problem on your own, perhaps you could edit your query to demonstrate your solution.

Comment: With respect to the 2nd part of Sunshine's answer, the following question may be productive re stretching your intuition.  Suppose $T$ is chosen so that $T = \max\{ ~|k|, ~|K| ~\}.$  Then $T$ is a *tighter* bound on the sequence $\langle a_n\rangle.$  It might be helpful for you to try to prove that here, $-T$ is a lower bound and $T$ is an upper bound for the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded, then there exists $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $|a_n| \leq K$, thus $-K \leq a_n \leq K$. Hence $(a_n)$ is bounded below by $-K$ and bounded above by $K$. Thus a bounded sequence is bounded below and bounded above.

Conversely suppose $(a_n)$ is bounded below by $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and bounded above by $K \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have
$$k \leq a_n \leq K \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \text{ for all }\text{ }n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Since $$-|k|-|K| \leq k \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }K \leq |k|+|K|$$
Then $$k \leq a_n \leq K \Rightarrow -|k|-|K| \leq a_n \leq |k|+|K|\Rightarrow|a_n| \leq |k|+|K|$$.

Thus we conclude that $ a_n $ is bounded by $|k|+|K|$